function called using .then() is executed before the function on which then() is chained completes
In the onSelected function of a DropDownMenu widget, a function which returns a Future is called. After that Future completes, a regular function must be executed. In order to do this, am using the then keyword, as follows:
Serialize.deSerialize().then((e) => updateStatusbar());

The signature of the deserialize() method is:
static Future<void> deSerialize() async {

Within this method, there are several asynchronous calls using the await keyword, similar to the following:
await storage.read(key:'myKey'); 

The problem is that the updateStatusbar() method is called before the deSerialize() method has completed. I cannot call deSerialize() using await, because the DropDownMenu is defined within the build() method of widget, and that cannot be made async.
Adding print statements to verify the order of execution shows the following:
flutter: inside deSerialize 1
flutter: inside deSerxialize 2
flutter: inside deSerialize 3
flutter: inside deSerialize 4
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 1
flutter: end of deSerialize
flutter: in updateStatusbar 1
flutter: in updateStatusbar 2
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 2
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 3
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 4
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 5
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 6
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 7
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 8
flutter: inside method called from deSerialize 10
flutter: end of methods called from deSerialize

Most of the functions called using await within deSerialize() are called after the ones in updateStatusBar().
What is the correct way to chain these function calls so that deSerialize() only returns to then() after all the functions called within deSerialize() using await have finished?
Thanks very much

add some print at the end of deSerialize and also inside then's callback and post the logs (and the changed source code)

Thank you very much. Have edited the question to better explain the issue

how do you know that "most of the functions called using await within deSerialize() are called after the ones in updateStatusBar()"?

Have edited the question to show the print outputs

as i can see end of deSerialize is always called at the end - after any inside method called from deSerialize ...

but updatetatusBar() is being called before that

called by who? with no source code it is not possible to say anything

Its is called using then(): Serialize.deSerialize().then((e) => updateStatusbar());

so where is that print inside then;s callback? i dont see it - maybe  updatetatusBar is called by some other code

'in updateStatusbar 1' is the print statement within the then() callback, updateStatusbar(), which is not called from anywhere else

You need to post a reproducible example.  It is simply impossible that updateStatusbar() is called before the Future returned by Serialize.deSerialize() completes.  You almost certainly aren't observing what you think you are.  As pskink mentioned, perhaps updateStatusbar() is called by something else (perhaps from an earlier call to Serialize.deSerialize()) or perhaps Serialize.deSerialize returns a Future that completes before you expect it to.

The Future returned by Serialize.deSerialize() does complete before  updateStatusbar() is called. However, the Futures which have been called within Serialize.deSerialize() do NOT complete first, and continue to run separately.

"However, the Futures which have been called within Serialize.deSerialize() do NOT complete first" - how did you call them? why don't you simply post the code? did you await all of them?

That was the issue, now it works. Thanks very much for your help

The function updateStatusBar is called after deserialize has completed.
I would recommend restructuring your code and if the widget you are building depends on a Future value then rather use a FutureBuilder.

Reply to comment: I still don't understand the problem, since the onSelected callback of a DropDownMenu can be marked async.

The widget does not depend on a Future, rather the onSelected event needs to call a function which returns a Future. I also edited the question to include print output to clarify the order of execution

Reply: See last paragraph of answer post.

it was. The issue was that the async functions it was calling were not using the await keyword

The issue was that within the deSerialize() itself, I was not using await to call the other Futures. Now it works
